# 404 Page Not Found related codeigniter when do upload data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got error '404 Page Not Found' when I try to upload file in my website url .

```
http://www.myurl.com/myfolderadmin/
```

but when I do the same thing in localhost it's work well.

```
http://localhost/mycmsname/myfolderadmin/
```

this is piece of my controller:

```
  function insert() {
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '*column must be filled');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'Judul', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('isi', 'Isi', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $this->layout->addJs('ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
  $this->layout->addJs('js/admin/b267648789c30a07b0efa5bce7bdd9fe.js');
  $this->layout->view('myfolderadmin/subfolder/myview');
} else {
  $data = array(
      'title' => $this->input->post('judul'),
      'content' => $this->input->post('isi'),
  );
  $this->db->insert('newses', $data);
  $judul = $this->input->post('judul');

  $this->load->helper('file');
  $pictureFiles = get_filenames('picture_news');

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('newses');
  $this->db->where('title', $judul);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $id = $row->id;
    $post_date = $row->post_date;
  }

  $datapic = array(
      'pictureFiles' => $pictureFiles,
      'id' => $id,
      'post_date' => $post_date,
      'title' => $this->input->post('judul'),
      'content' => $this->input->post('isi'),
  );

  $this->layout->view('myfolderadmin/subfolder/myview', $datapic);
  //}
}
```

}

what's wrong? how I fix it?

thanks for the answer.

Comment: you need to modify your .htaccess
the base url should match your server

Answer (score 0):

Empty yout .htaccess file and add the following,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|public|themes|captcha|robots|documents|\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps you....

Comment: @Amit_Horakeri : I think my htaccess file work well. this my htaccess file:
 Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myfolder/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>